# Maven: Rename the application EAR

Tags: java, maven, war, ear

I have a maven 2 ear modules.

For example, its artifact ID is MyApp. Maven creates ear archives whith name MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear

I want to change default name.

I have this in the parent pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

And this in the ear pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: @SafwenKhalloufi you should vote the answers instead of writing thanks. Also you should mark an answer as accepted if that solves your problem.

Comment: @AndreiI The answer that solves my problem is mine, so I can't accept it today

Comment: @SafwenKhalloufi not a problem, I just noticed that you have a bad rate of accepted answers/questions. You should review them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>pitupload-business</finalName>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look for **finalName** tag under the plugin

[maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html)

```
  <build>
       <finalName>YourCool-Name</finalName>   
  <build>
```

Comment: No! Remove the .ear. Also, now your answer is almost exactly the same as arghtype's

Comment: @blackbuild ups, ear - good catch. About answers, I did not notice that, as mine was the first here. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Provide final name for your artifact

```
<build>
     <finalName>NAME</finalName>  
     ... 
<build>
```

Comment: Use ${project.artifactId} instead of NAME.

Comment: TS didn't specify name he wants. Sometimes there is a need to use really specific name: for example, some time ago I found out that jboss7 didn't accept artifacts with '-' in its' name, so I have to use custom name with '.' in one specific build profile.